Ошибка при подключении библиотеки 'OPENCV'
Я использую компилятор 'GCC' и 'CMake' для работы с кодом 'C'. После установки библиотеки 'OpenCV' в свой проект и её вызове в коде - выдаёт ошибку:

"fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory. compilation
terminated."

Похоже 'GCC' не видит путь до папки с библиотекой, но как и куда прописать его, и можно ли сделать это через терминал ?
код: (Ругается на конец строки #include <cv.h> )
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>  

int main(void)
{

}

